# If Formula with formulas in Value if true/false

Tags: excel, excel-formula

so my formula is below. If the total in cells E16-20 is greater than 240 (If true) then the cell needs to equal E21 divided by .3 (30% of E21) if it is FALSE than the cell just needs to equal E21
It just comes up with #NAME?

`=IF(sum=E16:E20>240,(sum=E21/0.3),(E21))`

Comment: This is correct syntax: `=IF(SUM(E16:E20)>240,E21*30%,E21)`

Comment: THANKYOU!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
=IF(sum(E16:E20)>240, E21*0.3, E21)
```